# How to update vscode's terminal icon and have it persist?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example this is my default terminal icon. I want to update the icon to `terminal-bash` and have it persist when I open a new terminal.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a [terminal profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles)

There you can specify the icon to use: use `terminal-bash` or `$(terminal-bash)` for the icon ID